# CSS-based image slideshow won't scale to height:100% on mobile devices

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, css-selectors

So I have this imgSlider on a website i'm working on which is purely run by css and on a desktop/laptop i have no issues with how this slider looks or performs.

However on mobile devices I would like the slider to fill the height of the screen and any overflow to be hidden. I tried removing `max-width` and setting `height:100%` but that seems to have no effect. I have also tried `object-fit` but again I am having no luck in getting the slider to fill height whilst maintaining aspect ratio.

**Note:** I have a media query set up already, more of the fact I can't get the imgSlider to fill height wise.

My code for the slider is below - appreciate any help or advice people can give!

**HTML:**

```
<main>
  <div class="imgContain">
     <img class="bannerPhoto" src="images/Banner1.jpg" alt="Brides | One">
     <img class="bannerPhoto" src="images/Banner2.jpg" alt="Brides | Two">
     <img class="bannerPhoto" src="images/Banner3.jpg" alt="Brides | Three">
     <img class="bannerPhoto" src="images/Banner4.jpg" alt="Brides | Four">
     <img class="bannerPhoto" src="images/Banner5.jpg" alt="Brides | Five">
     <img class="ghostPhoto" src="images/Banner1.jpg" alt="Brides | One">
  </div>
</main>
```

**CSS:**

```
/* imgSlider */

.imgContain{
    max-width:100%;
    height:auto;
    margin:0.1em auto;
    overflow:hidden;
    position:relative;
}

.ghostPhoto {
    width:100%;
    visibility:hidden;
    position:relative;
}

.bannerPhoto{
    width:100%;
    position:absolute;
    animation:round 50s infinite;
    opacity:0;
}

@keyframes round{   
    15%{opacity:1;}
    45%{opacity:0;}
} 

img.bannerPhoto:nth-child(1){animation-delay:0s;}
img.bannerPhoto:nth-child(2){animation-delay:10s;}
img.bannerPhoto:nth-child(3){animation-delay:20s;}
img.bannerPhoto:nth-child(4){animation-delay:30s;}
img.bannerPhoto:nth-child(5){animation-delay:40s;}
```

Comment: Can I have a link to the website? I would like to see what it currently looks like to have a better understanding of the problem.

Comment: @Bagel03 of course - it's: https://www.beautybybhav.com